# Django -> dict access template from context_proccesor function

Tags: django

Context_procesor

```
from .models import MdPaginas
def fn_mdpaginas(request):
    mdpaginas = dict()
    paginas = MdPaginas.objects.all()
    for pagina in paginas:
        mdpaginas[pagina.title] = pagina.id
    print('procesador de paginas ->', mdpaginas)
    return mdpaginas
```

Print shows 3 dict items upon console.
How ever this template code fail:

```
{% for id, titulo in mdpaginas.items  %}
   <p>
     {{titulo}} hola
   </p>
{% empty %}
   No hay paginas  
{% endfor %}
```

HTML shows -> 'No hay paginas'

¿ What´s my error ?
¿ What can I do to use dict ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the *keys* from your context processor are added to the template context. The dictionary itself is not added to the context.

If you want to do `{% for pagina in mdpaginas %}` in your template, then you need to return a dictionary containing `mdpaginas`:

```
def fn_mdpaginas(request):
    mdpaginas = dict()
    paginas = MdPaginas.objects.all()
    for pagina in paginas:
        mdpaginas[pagina.id] = pagina.titulo  # Note I've reversed the key/values from your answer
    print('procesador de paginas ->', mdpaginas)
    out = {'mdpaginas': mdpaginas}
    return out
```

Note that it might be simpler to return the queryset in your context processor:

```
def fn_mdpaginas(request):
    return {'mdpaginas': MdPaginas.objects.all()}
```

The in your template you can do:

```
{% for mdpagina in mdpaginas %}
  <p>
    {{ mdpagina.titulo }}
  </p>
{% empty %}
  No hay paginas  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it in the view's context for the template to be able to access it. Something like this:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import MdPaginas

def fn_mdpaginas(request):
    paginas = MdPaginas.objects.all()
    context = {'mdpaginas': paginas}
    template_name = 'your_app/your_template.html'
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Then in your template you could access it like:

```
{% for pagina in mdpaginas  %}
   <p>
     {{pagina.titulo}} hola
   </p>
{% empty %}
   No hay paginas  
{% endfor %}
```

I'd suggest you take a look here to understand Function Based Views better: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/

Comment: I want to have a processor function in order to have available dict for every html templates. This dict contains items for all HTML Footers.